# One plus doesn't receive device id from GCM over 4G

Tags: android, angularjs, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, oneplusone

I'm using Ionic & Angular to build my APP and all works fine in Samsung devices. However I encounter some problems using my One Plus. When I try to sign in on GCM using data connection I get an empty device id back from GCM, but it works just fine over wifi.

Can someone help me out here?